# How to start the james service in debug mode?

Tags: java, james

i am running james as window service.I have put my mailet their in config.file which further calls my my application specific libs.  Now i want to debug the some classes in my application once i receive the mail. I am not getting how to start the james window service in  debug mode so that i can connect to same port from my eclipse and start debugging.

One more thing is james server works fine when i start it as window service but once is start  it using James.bat file it gives some errors related to my application. so looks like  running james from James.bat  is out. Please provide your inputs how i can start james service in debug mode. james version is 2.3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

James doesn't support start in debug mode, so you have to start it in debug mode by yourself.
For James 3 (beta) it's easy, I assume you can use this solution for version 2.3.2 as well.

1. First create `rundebug.bat` file in `JAMES\bin` directory with the following content:

   > set JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
   >
   > run.bat
2. Run it from command line. James server is now ready for remote debugging.
3. In Eclipse, create a new "Remote Java Application" in Debug Configurations dialog with default configuration. In "Project" field choose the project that contains the mailets you want to debug.
4. Place breakpoints and run the configuration.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You should uncomment following row in JAMES_HOME/bin/run.bat to get enable remote debugging:
from

```
rem set DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

to

```
set DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```